# Get android seekbar value and display it on screen

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the value of the seek bar whenever it changes and display it underneath. I'm using the `onclick` method on my seekbar to call this method.

```
public void getNumber(View view) 
{
    SeekBar seek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    int seekValue = seek.getProgress();
    String x = "Value: " + Integer.toString(seekValue);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.level)).setText(x);
}
```

Comment: Create OnSeekbarChanged event, and fill a variable with the value from the seekbar(.GetValue), then send it to a label

Comment: @Mobstaa, could you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here some extra help:

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.SeekBar; 
import android.widget.TextView; 

public class AndroidSeekBar extends Activity { 
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
   @Override 
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
       setContentView(R.layout.main); 

       SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar); 
       final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekbarvalue); 

       seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){ 

   @Override 
   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, 
     boolean fromUser) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress)); 
   } 

   @Override 
   public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
   } 

   @Override 
   public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
   } 
       }); 
   } 
}
```

use the `OnProgressChanged` event to check the progress of the seekbar, you can return that int to use it somewhere else in your app.

Comment: where do you put this code? Create a new .java file and plop it in?

Comment: You could do that, but there should already be a file in your current project where you can put your code.

Comment: What if I want to get the progress before it is changed, let's say during on create?

Comment: @Si8 you should be able to access it from the onCreate method. I think calling getProgress() on seekBar should do the trick.