# Android - Create a settings object similar to volume control

Tags: android

As the title says, I was wondering if there is a way to add a way to create input in my Android application, by providing the user with a bar similar to the one used by Android system for adjusting the sound volume. A specific variable would change its value, according to the position of a "button" on the bar (sorry for my English). Any advice on that?

Comment: are you looking for this 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SeekBar` is what you are looking for.

Here is the design spec: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/sliders.html#

Here is the reference page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html

If you want to set the value of the position of the `SeekBar`, simply do:

```
seekBar.setProgress(position);
```

where `position` is where you want the `SeekBar` to be.

Getting the position of the `SeekBar` is a bit more involved. Firstly you must set a `setOnSeekBarChangeListener` and grab the `SeekBar` value from within the `onProgressChanged` method. This is a StackOverflow question that answers this well: [get android seekbar value and display it on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326290/get-android-seekbar-value-and-display-it-on-screen)