# How to show the seekBar value in another class?

Tags: android, set, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have two list in **Activity A**. The value inside the listView were getting from **Activity B**. When the list is clicked, it suppose to go **Activity B**.

[image]

For the Progress value in A, it actually get from the seekBar.

Assume first list is clicked, the seekBar should shows 36 instead of 0 ! This is what I've tried so far.

[image]

**Activity A**

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // if listView is clicked
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Object o = listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                SearchResults fullObject = (SearchResults) o;
                String temp = fullObject.getDescription();
                String[] ReceiveDescription = temp.split(":");
                String Progress=fullObject.getProgress();
                String[] ReceiveProgress=Progress.split(":");
                String TimeIn=fullObject.getTimeIn();
                String []ReceiveTimeIn=TimeIn.split(":");
                String TimeOut=fullObject.getTimeOut();
                String []ReceiveTimeOut=TimeOut.split(":");

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(), Add_Details_Information.class);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveProject", ReceiveProject);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveDescription", ReceiveDescription[1]);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveProgress", ReceiveProgress[1].getProgress()); //cannot resolve getProgress
                i.putExtra("ReceiveTimeIn", ReceiveTimeIn[1]);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveTimeOut", ReceiveTimeOut[1]);
                i.putExtra("date",date);
                i.putExtra("status", status);
                startActivityForResult(i,PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Activity B**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_details_information);
        addItemsOnSpinner(); // Spinner for project/service/training
        tp = new TimePick(); // call tmePick
        description=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextWorkDescription);
        timeIn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.TimeIn);
        timeOut=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.TimeOut);
        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBarPercentage);
        progressText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textProgress);
        progressText.setText("Covered:" + "" + seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax());

        if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
        {
            final String Project1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveProject");
            final String Description1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveDescription");
            final int Progress1=getIntent().getIntExtra("ReceiveProgress",0);
            final String TimeIn1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveTimeIn");
            final String TimeOut1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveTimeOut");
            // project.setText(Project1);

            description.setText(Description1);
            timeIn.setText(TimeIn1);
            timeOut.setText(TimeOut1);
            seekBar.setProgress(Progress1);
           // Toast.makeText(this,Progress1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressText.setText("Covered:" + "" + seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
        }
```

Comment: You want `seekbar` value only or want to show `seekbar` progress to the value to you are getting.

Comment: @Clairvoyant I want to show `seekbar progress`

Comment: Have you added `setOnSeekBarChangeListener`?

Comment: So are you getting values in `Progress` string in Activity A??

Comment: @Jas no. Where should I add?

Comment: Refer this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326290/get-android-seekbar-value-and-display-it-on-screen

Comment: @Clairvoyant ya. For string Progress, I get `Progress: 36`. So I split it and pass the 36 value to B.

Comment: @Jas erm..the answer not what I want.

Comment: When the list in A is clicked, it should show 36 in seekBar activity B, not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of below line:

```
i.putExtra("ReceiveProgress", ReceiveProgress[1].getProgress()); //cannot resolve getProgress
```

Change it to below code in **Activity A**

```
//checking array length if its greater than 1 then you can get value from index 1 
if(ReceiveProgress.length > 1){
   i.putExtra("ReceiveProgress", Integer.parseInt(ReceiveProgress[1])); 
 }
```

**ReceiveProgress** is `string array` and your sending it as `string` and as an `integer` and in `Activity B` you are fetching it as `Integer`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but `getProgress()` still cannot be resolved

Comment: Check whether `ReceiveProgress` array having value `36` at index 1 or not. otherwise check index 0 for value.

Comment: I checked like this  `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Progress+ ""+ReceiveProgress[1],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` and it shows `Progress : 36` `36`

Comment: Did I need to change anything in my Activity B ?

Comment: No you dont have to change anything in `activity b`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96526/discussion-between-john-and-clairvoyant).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `seekbar.setprogress`(required value) if you want to show seekbar progress at one point and you can add `seekbar` listener if you want to measure `seekbar` value at every point.
Send  `i.putExtra("ReceiveProgress", ReceiveProgress[1].getProgress());` from activity A to B and in B , set `seekbar.setprogresss(Integer.parseInt(ReceiveProgress[1].getProgress()))`.

Hope it helps.